# How do I fix ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor' when installing pip dependencies in docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am new to Airflow, trying to use it with Docker containers. I have a docker-compose setup which works well in my smaller test scenarios, but I've encountered problems when trying to get all my python dependencies installed in order for my more advanced dags to get properly imported to my webserver UI. So, originally I tried to solve the problem "No module named...", since my dependencies weren't installed.

I've tried a few different things so far (alot of which came from other threads here on SO):

- Adding the dependencies to the _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS in my docker-compose. This works to get rid of the "No module named.."-error, but it took more than an hour to startup (and will take > 1hour each time..). As far as I've understood, adding python packages like this it's not recommended at all, so there are probably more reasons for using extended docker images as well, of which I am unaware.
- Extending the apache/airflow:2.5.2 image I'm using for my docker container in accordance to this howto: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#docker-compose-env-variables , the approach described under the title "Special case - adding dependencies via requirements.txt file", ie use a Dockerfile containing the following:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2 
ADD requirements.txt . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

- Extending the apache/airflow:2.5.2 image using a Dockerfile using COPY for requirements instead of ADD:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2 
COPY /requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

- Extending the apache/airflow:2.5.2 image using a Dockerfile like this (but with all of the requirements from requirements.txt):

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2 
RUN pip install requirement1
RUN pip install requirement2
RUN pip install requirement3
```

- Extending the apache/airflow:2.5.2 image using a Dockerfile like this (but with all of the requirements from requirements.txt):

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2 
RUN pip install requirement1 requirement2 requirement3
```

For all of the above, I follow the instructions in the default docker-compose.yaml for airflow regarding building:

```
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  build: .
  #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.2}
  environment:
...
```

So I do:

```
docker compose build
docker compose up airflow-init
```

All of the above gives me the same problem when running docker compose up airflow-init:

```
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | 
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | Last check result:
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | $ airflow db check
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 736, in configure_handler
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     result = factory(**kwargs)
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 49, in __init__
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     Path(self._get_log_directory()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | TypeError: mkdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | 
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | 
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     from airflow.__main__ import main
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     settings.initialize()
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 570, in initialize
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     raise e
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     dictConfig(logging_config)
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 800, in dictConfig
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 571, in configure
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  |     '%r' % name) from e
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1  | 
ml_pipeline-airflow-init-1 exited with code 1

ValueError: Unable to configure handler ’processor'
```

Weirdly enough, the problem doesn't occur when I extend the image with only one of the requirements, ie using a Dockerfile such as:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2
RUN pip install requirement1
```

Does anyone know what this might be caused by or how I can do this another way? I am happy to provide more information if needed of course.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your requirements is somehow downgrading the pathlib version? Or masking `Path`... somehow? I'm asking because the root exception seems to be `mkdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'`. That argument was added on version 3.5 (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)) I know nothing, and I'm probably wrong but... dunno... maybe it'll give you somewhere else to look for?

Comment: @BorrajaX thanks for the tip, I'll try to look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @BorrajaX in a comment, this had something to do with pathlib, which was one of the requirements I tried to install. However, since python 3.4, pathlib is already included in the standard library. Removing pathlib from the requirements.txt solved the problem, so my guess is the cause of this were some conflicting versions of pathlib...

Comment: Yay! Glad I helped!  Since this is the answer that fixed your problem, may I suggest you mark it as "chosen" (the tick under the answer's votes). Even though (since it's an answer to your own question) it won't increase your reputation, It will help future visitors of StackOverflow that find the question know that it has a valid answer (that it was solved)